# Package temperature above threshold false alarms

Tags: lenovo, overheating, temperature

My kern.log has this kind of song and dance every 5 minutes:

```
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849080] CPU6: Core temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849081] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849082] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849082] CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849083] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849083] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849118] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849119] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849120] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 20:56:41 cabron kernel: [99978.849120] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143135] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1213)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143136] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4841)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143137] CPU7: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1213)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143138] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4841)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143140] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4841)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143144] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4841)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143177] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4841)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143178] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4841)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143179] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4841)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.143180] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4841)
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144334] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144335] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144335] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144336] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144337] CPU7: Core temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144337] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144338] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144338] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144376] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Sep 10 21:02:58 cabron kernel: [100355.144376] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
```

Now, I'm running PSensors while using the machine, so I know what the temperature is. It's stable around 50 degrees C, with occasional slight bumps.  I tend to never hear the fans run.

[image: screenshot psensors]

My questions are:

1. What's going on here?
2. What is the threshold temperature?
3. How can I stop this polluting my kern.log?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04LTS on a Lenovo X1 Carbon running the latest 1.30 firmware. Previous firmware versions also exhibited this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that PSensors is correct? I know instances where sensors and software didn't have the same standards, thus showing a wrong temp.

Answer (score 1):

There is a probably a bug, but may this workaround helps you: https://github.com/erpalma/lenovo-throttling-fix

Comment: It's been almost 2 years and it's still the problem. Lenovo ThinkPad T480 here with around month old Ubuntu 18.04. [First I noticed my syslog and journal taking whole disk space, then monitored my logs and noticed this regular "overheating" while I'm in an air-conditioned room...]

Comment: Did you solve it?