# Core/Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled - Lenovo E590

Tags: boot, 18.04, lenovo, cpu, temperature

I a new Linux user and this is my second question.
Here is my problem:

I just got a new computer (Lenovo Thinkpad E590 i7-8565) and I successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 Pro. So, I have both OS available when I boot and I made a third NTFS partition where I can store my files which can be accessed on Linux and on Windows 10.

Sometimes when I boot on Ubuntu, I got this showing up:

Output for `$ cat /var/log/kern.log`:

```
mce: CPU6: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
```

I got stuck between this screen and the Ubuntu loading screen.

My only option is to press the power button and to restart my computer again. After 2 or 3 tries, my Ubuntu finally starts (but those errors are still showed)

I checked the temperature of my CPU right after and everything seems to by normal.

Output for `$ sensors`:

```
thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

I already tried that fix here: https://github.com/erpalma/throttled, but it didn't work for my Lenovo E590.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

PS.: I had an issue that I solved a few weeks ago where my motherboard made a very hard and long beep. The beep started when I did boot my computer and ended when I left GRUB. This was an issue with the kernel that I had to update. So now, my kernel is 5.0.7-generic.
As a new Linux user, I don't really know if there is a correlation between this and my current issue. So I just put it here just in case.

**EDIT:** I always update and upgrade my Ubuntu periodically and I didn't have this issue since a while. I suppose this is due to a particular update. So I leave this topic unsolved in the case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Might be an answer to your problem here.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073948/package-temperature-above-threshold-false-alarms?rq=1

Comment: @crip659 I already tried this. The error messages don't show anymore but I remain stuck between this black screen and the Ubuntu loading screen. So, I uninstalled the tool afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update my kernel regularly and this issues never occurred since a while, so I suppose this issue has been fixed in one of those updates.

So I'll close this post.